# Skip login form wp-login.php when already logged in,

Tags: login

I have a plugin that redirects to different pages after login filtered by user role. To get user roles back on their 'custom' page when they have navigated away from it I had the idea to send them back to the login page so they'll get redirected to the custom page again. But when I send users to the login page they'll be met with the login form even when they're already logged in. Is it possible to skip the form when logged in and go straight to the redirect?

Comment: Can u please show your latest code.

Comment: I don't have any code. It's the wp-login.php page that comes with Wordpress, so I'm guessing showing the login form even when you're already logged in is the default behavior. All I did is installing the login/logout redirect plugin.